How to get a mesh to align evenly with imported stl so that you can use boolean to join them together
I'm new to blender and need to do some hard surface modelling to modify an imported stl. I'm trying to align this cube with one of the sides of the imported stl but cannot get it to become perfectly flat with the object. I've been using the grab tool and scale tool but cannot get the cube mesh to become even with the imported stl, some parts of it is even but others aren't. Could this be a rotational issue? Afterwards, I need to use boolean to join the cube to the surface but is there a way to align them perfectly first?



Can you share your Blender project file? Instructions for sharing.
